# Scroll to top in tab bar when view controller is already showing

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

I am attempting to get the feed in my view controller to scroll to the top but only if the tab bar icon is tapped and the view controller is already showing. The following code incorrectly scrolls to the top when the view controller is not showing but the tap bar is clicked. I checked other stack overflow solutions and didn't find one that used didselectitem... 
Why doesn't my code work?

Here's my code:

```
 -(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==0 && [self.tabBarController indexOfAccessibilityElement:item]==0) {
    //broadcast a notifcation to scroll to the top of the newsfeed....
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             postNotificationName:@"scrollToTopWhenIconTapped"
     object:self];
}
}
```